# Is there a way to simply `select * from myTable` and get the timestamps as Unix time?

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I'm saving DateTime data in mySql as timestamps, and I need to retrieve the  data as Unix timestamps.

I can use `select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestampData) from myTable`.

But I usually `select * from myTable1 join myTable2 on ....` wich in some cases can get up to 50 fields.

which means I have to either :

- option 1 : `select *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp1), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp2) from myTables` 
  and I'll get the data twice and hard to maintain
- option 2 :`select c1, c2, c3,... , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp1), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp2) from myTables` . This would be harder to write and maintain.

The question is **Is there a way to simply `select * from myTable` and get the timestamps as Unix time?**

Comment: No there isn't. If you wanted that, you should have stored them as unix timestamps in the first place.

Comment: You don't want select all fields with *. This is bad practice. You should select only needed fields.

Comment: what happens if you alias the unix_timestamped fields with the same field name? SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp1) AS timestamp1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp2) AS timestamp2 ...   It might help that duplicated field values will be overwritten from first to last, but it depends on your controller which is unknown in the question.

Comment: Try this: `select myTable1.*, myTable2.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp1) as unix_timestamp1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp2) as unix_timestamp2,  from myTable1 join myTable2 on ...`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to handle this would probably be to parse the time upon receipt in your application. Other than that, option 2 is how I usually see these things done in a professional environment.